# The selectedItem is returning the samevalue no matter what is chosen in DropDownList in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this dropdownl list defined in aspx page.

```
 <td style=" font-family:Consolas; ">Select the Category</td>
 <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_cat" runat="server"  Width="100px"  > 
 </asp:DropDownList></td>
```

And its codebehind is:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from main_catTbl", sc.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ddl_cat.DataSource = ds;
    ddl_cat.DataTextField = "material";
    ddl_cat.DataValueField = "mid";
    string a = ddl_cat.SelectedItem.Value;
    ddl_cat.DataBind();
    sc.con.Dispose();
    sc.con.Close();
```

The items are displayed on the dropdown list.But when i select some item and use

 `string st = ddl_cat.SelectedItem.Value` It always shows the first item of the dropdownlist.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your function containing the above codebehind(in your question) is not called on a posted back.I mean it should be called on pageload not posted back.
ie.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        your_function();

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that the above code is given under Data_bound event of the combo box, isn't it? 
to get the selected value the code must be given as follows

```
private void ddl_cat_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string a = ddl_cat.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Comment: I am supposed to get the function you mentioned here on double clicking the dropdownlidt in the design view.Right? But i am getting nothing.Why?

Comment: OK i got it.Apparently the dropdownlist isnt clickable if kept inside table like `<td><asp:DropDownList.....></td>`.But what if i need the dropdownlist in this particular format ie inside 'Table`.

Comment: By the way you can use this statement `string a = ddl_cat.SelectedItem.Value;` without necessarily creating the function as defined above.You can directly use the statement inside other function of the same .aspx.cs page.But it is not allowed in the function where you are binding the dropdownlist as you have provided in your codebehing.That is wrong.